# Convert a simple ajax call to use promise jQuery/AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, promise

I have this general method to use AJAX calls in a app:

```
function doAjaxCommand(url, type, async, params, successCallback, failCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        async: async,
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(params)
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(result) {
            if (result.Success) {
                successCallback(result);
            } else {
                if (failCallback !== undefined) {
                    failCallback(result);
                }
                return false;
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(status);
        }    
    });
}
```

I heard that using promises I can take a better use from async operations. However, I have no clue how to use promises. I've never used it, and I don't get the whole idea in some links I read about. Can you guys please give me a light about it? Even how to start thinking?

Any help would be apreciated, thank you!

Comment: add `return ` before `$.ajax(`. that's it.

Comment: try reading this, it talks about how to use the $q library: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: You almost certainly should not be using jQuery with Angular. Use Angular's `$http` service.

Comment: Eh... just put a `return` before the $.ajax` it already uses promises, you just hook on them with `.then`. Also, what m59 said.

Answer (score 3):

Actually promises allow a better way to 'compose' callbacks. Regular callbacks usually result in a 'Pyramid of doom'.

```
    step1(function (value1) {
        step2(value1, function(value2) {
            step3(value2, function(value3) {
              step4(value3, function(value4) {
                // Do something with value4
              });
          });
        });
    });
```

Instead promises allow a flattened call flow. eg: using q.js(https://github.com/kriskowal/q) we can do

```
Q.fcall(promisedStep1)
.then(promisedStep2)
.then(promisedStep3)
.then(promisedStep4)
.then(function (value4) {
    // Do something with value4
})
.catch(function (error) {
// Handle any error from all above steps
})
.done();
```

jquery also supports the promise style

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "example.json", function() {
     console.log( "success" );
})
.done(function() {
    console.log( "second success" );
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
   console.log( "complete" );
});
```

However you should use the angular promises which is built in.

Comment: jquery promises are described here http://api.jquery.com/promise/ and here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: jQuery's `.done` `.fail` `.always` etc are __nothing__ like Q's promises' `.then` or Angular's promises since they _don't chain_. Instead, you can compare it to jQuery's own `.then`.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Agreed that Q and Angular promises are superior https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/Coming-from-jQuery is a good article comparing them. I merely mentioned that jquery supports promise "style" and not that these are A+ promise compliant.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be the best thing to explain Angularjs promises to me:

http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html

If you plan on interacting with a backend regularly and restfully, I'd recommend [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular)

In angularjs, if you want to use the default `$http`, referencing Angular's docs:

```
 $http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'}).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // this callback will be called asynchronously
      // when the response is available
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // called asynchronously if an error occurs
      // or server returns response with an error status.
    });
```

This exposes the promise `success` and `error`
Or you can do

```
 $http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'}).
    then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // this callback will be called asynchronously
      // when the response is available
      $scope.users = response.users;
    })
```

Which expose the `then` promise of when the aync is finished, then do something.

Comment: Nice way using `$http` AngularJS object, but is there something like the `beforeSend` property as jQuery Ajax call has?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140591/what-is-the-equivalent-of-jquery-ajax-beforesend-in-angularjs gives you the answer to that. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http has the documentation about it. I personally have no used `.interceptors` myself but it'd be interesting to learn about it!